# Using callable to pass two parameters and returning an array of parameters

Tags: java, arrays, callable

I have to pass two strings to a thread, which will return an array containing both of them, and I must use callable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class toArray implements Callable<String[]> {

private String string1 string2;

public toArray (String first, String second)
{
    string1= first;
    string2 = second;
}

    @Override
    public String[] call() throws Exception {
        String [] allStrings = null;
            allStrings[0] = string1;
            allStrings[1] = string2;
        return allStrings;
    }
}
```

Below is the main:

```
public class theFuntion{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        FutureTask<String[]> task = new FutureTask (new MyCallable());
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        es.submit (task);
        try{
               String[] result = task.get();
               System.out.println(result[1] + result[2]);
           }
        catch(Exception e){
                           System.err.println(e);
    }
         es.shutdown();
}
```

The problem is in `main`: it says that result is expecting a String[] but it's getting an object.  If I cast result it will say an exception must be declared to be thrown.

Comment: Do you get any errors or strange behaviour ?

Comment: One issue I notice immediately is that you don't state you'll return `String[]` in your method signature, despite you attempting to do so anyway.

Comment: Another one is that `allStrings` is initialized with `null` and then reused. You, probably wanted `String [] allStrings = new String[2]`

Comment: This isn't exactly an error (but if you want my opinion, it should be): class names in Java should start with an uppercase letter. So `ToArray` and not `toArray`.

Comment: the problem i get is in the main: it says that result is expecting a String[] but it's getting an object. If i cast result, it will say an exception must be declared to be thrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the signature of the class to

```
public class toArray implements Callable<String[]>
```

and the signature of the `call` method to

```
public String[] call() throws Exception
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, there are more than one error...
See the following working sample

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        FutureTask<String[]> task = new FutureTask(new MyCallable("a", "b"));
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        es.submit (task);
        try{
            String[] result = task.get();
            System.out.println(result[0] + result[1]);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        es.shutdown();
    }

    public static class MyCallable implements Callable<String[]>
    {

        private String string1, string2;

        public MyCallable (String first, String second)
        {
            string1= first;
            string2 = second;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] call() throws Exception {
            String [] allStrings = new String[2];
            allStrings[0] = string1;
            allStrings[1] = string2;
            return allStrings;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there an exception? Did you change the initialization of `allStrings = null` to `allStrings = new String[2]`? And change the class name `toArray`to `MyCallable`

Answer (score 2):

In [`Callable<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), the parameterized type `V` stands for the result type of [`call()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call%28%29). Since you want to return a `String[]`, instead of `Callable<String>`, use `Callable<String[]>`. Then, change the return type of `call` to `String[]`:

```
@Override
public String[] call() throws Exception {
    String [] allStrings = new String[2];
    allStrings[0] = string1;
    allStrings[1] = string2;
    return allStrings;
}
```

<sub>As a side note, class names in Java [should](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) be nouns, and should start with an uppercase letter.</sub>

Comment: "Then, change the return type of call to String[]:"
as in return allStrings[];            ???

Comment: @Ryan: No, the return type is what's right after the `public` accessor. Instead of `public String call`, use `public String[] call`.  With this, you change the *return type* from String to String[].

Comment: You have many other errors in your code. For example, what's `new MyCallable()`? Shouldn't it be `new toArray("some string", "otherString")`? Also, use `new FutureTask<String[]>`. `private String string1 string2;` is also not valid, either separate both variables with a comma `private String string1, string2;` or use two different statements. Finally, arrays in java are `0-indexed`, so the first position is [0] instead of [1].

Answer (score 1):

You have not referenced your `ToArray` class in `TheFunction`, probably due to compilation errors (hint: fixes have already been mentioned).

Your new FutureTask will look like:

```
FutureTask<String[]> task = new FutureTask(new ToArray("foo", "bar"));
```

Without telling you the bare answer, you will hit 2 exceptions in the `call()` method in `ToArray`:

- Firstly your String array is never initialised, but **should** be.
- All arrays start at zero

Comment: i did that edit: FutureTask<String[]> task = new FutureTask(new ToArray("foo", "bar"));
, thanks so much but still no change.